# Editing and emailing a page from a website

Tags: web, download, email-attachments

Is it possible to download a page from a website, edit parts of that webpage, save it and then email it to someone so they can see the changes?

I have been using "save as" "web page, complete" to download the page.  I can edit it locally but whenever I email this file either the stylesheet or the images do not appear correctly when they open it!

Is there a better way??

Comment: If the style is based on an external css file you have to download it too, and put its content between <style></style> into your new web page. But maybe it will not be enough if there are images with relative path...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to edit a web page using tools like edit.lize.it, but the best way of saving the result is to take a screenshot, like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Link: [edit.lize.it](http://edit.lize.it/)